# Adjusting axis range and tick marks in python ggplot

Tags: python, python-ggplot

Is there a way to be able to set both the axis range and the number of tick marks in the python implementation of ggplot for a scatterplot?  For example, I want to set the y-axis to be from 0 to 100 with a tick at values 0, 10, 20, 30,...,100.

I've tried the following:

```
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=data) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(limits=(0,100), breaks=range(0,100,10))
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=data) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(breaks=range(0,100,10)) + ylim(0,100)
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=data) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(breaks=range(0,100,10))
```

In the first two lines, the limits override the breaks, so I get an axis from 0 to 100 but the tick marks do not appear.  In the last line, the breaks do appear, but the range is only the automatic range that ggplot uses from the data, rather than the desired 0 to 100 range.

Comment: I'm simply not able to reproduce this problem with the test data included in `ggplot`.  Can you give an explicit example?  Otherwise this should be chalked up to it being an early version of `ggplot` (this question is 3 years old) and maybe we should close this question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem described here is currently not reproducible. Use ggplot 0.11.5 to remedy the problem.